# power series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ at $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

In an exercise I am asked to find the power series of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ centered at the point $1$.

**My approach:**

$$ \begin{align}
 \frac{1}{z^2+1} & =  \frac{1}{z^2+ 2 - 1}
\\
\\& = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}(1-z^2)}
\\
\\& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{2^n}(-1)^n(z^2-1)^n
\\
\\& = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}(z^2-1)^n
\end{align} $$

Using the Binomial theorem we get that:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}(z^2-1)^n & = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{n-k} z^{2k}
\\
\\ & = \sum_{n \geq 0}\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{(-1)^{2n-k}}{2^{n+1}} {n \choose k}  z^{2k}
\\
\\ & = \sum_{k \geq 0}\underbrace{\sum_{n\geq k}  \frac{(-1)^{2n-k}}{2^{n+1}} {n \choose k}}_{:=b_k}  z^{2k}
\\
\\ & = \sum_{k \geq 0} b_k z^{2k}
\end{align}$$

I got this result but I think that this is wrong for the following reason:

- A power series of a function centered at $a$ is written as: $\sum a_n (z-a)^n$, and I did not end up with something of that form

So how can I solve this problem and find a power series for the function $f$ centered at $a=1$?

Comment: Consider instead that $z=(z-1)+1$ giving$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)^2+2(z-1)+2}$$

Comment: How should I proceed from that point on?

Comment: Using the above you just need to equivalently find the Maclaurin series (expansion about $y=0$) of the function $1/(y^2+2y+2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$$

$$g(z)=f(z+1)=\frac{1}{1+(z+1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2+2z+z^2}$$
$$=\frac 12 \frac{1}{1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}}$$
$$=\frac 12\frac{1}{1-X}$$
with $$X=-z-\frac{z^2}{2}$$

expand $ g(z)$ around $ z=0 $ as
$$\frac 12(1+X+X^2+...)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$
to get the expansion of $ f $ around $ z=1 $ by using
$$f(z)=g(z-1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$$

Comment: the power series of a function $f$ centered at $a$ is the same as the power series of a function $g(z) = f(z-a)$ centered at 0?

Comment: $g(z)=f(z+a)$. if $ f$ is defined around $ a$ then $ g$ is defined around zero.